# is there a name for lattice subset of convex combination?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, combinations, convex-geometry

Given finite points $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$, the convex combination of them is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i, \alpha_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1$.

What if there is an extra constraint: $\alpha_i \in \{ \frac{0}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{n}{n} \}$. Is there a specific name for this type of combination?

E.g. One possible combination is: $\alpha_1 = \frac{n}{n}, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n = \frac{0}{n}$.

Comment: it's extra, so it's a proper subset of convex combination. why would they not add up to 1 ?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood.

Comment: no worries, thanks for the interest, let me add some concrete example in the problem description